# How can I change the graphics settings manually in the Crysis 2 demo?

Tags: crysis-2

In the Crysis 2 Demo, there are only 3 graphics options (gamer, advanced, hardcore).
Can I change graphics options manually, like I could do in Crysis?

Things like environment detail, anti-aliasing, anisotrophic filtering, shader quality, shadow, motion blur and so on.

Comment: There's a demo?! God I feel so out of touch.

Comment: @DavidYell: Don't worry, only since yesterday :)

Comment: You should try opening the dev-console ('--console' for a steam version), then list all avalaible command. I believe you can change graphics options from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1775803), especially [this post](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=21052192&postcount=6) helped a lot.
It's unpleasant for me to answer my own question, but there came no one to help.

Comment: It isn't unpleasant at all, the information you found could be useful to other people, and you've provided an easy way for them to find it.  That's a good thing.